# ruby .includes to return records from two different sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so I think my title is not descriptive enough but here's what I'm trying to do:

so here's my code

```
ProductDraft.includes(param_includes)
            .where.not(images: {id: nil})
            .where(images: {kind: ['', nil]})
```

`param_includes` is `[product_draft_variants: [:images], product: [variants: :images]]`

Now, `product_draft` has many `product_draft_variants` that has many `images` but at the same time a `product_draft` belongs to a `product` that has many `variants` with has many `images`.

What I want to happen in this query is to call all `product_draft` that has images both from `product_draft_variants` and from `product` but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

I've tried to modify `param_includes` to
`[product_draft_variants: [:images]]` only and it returns all `product_draft` with images  through `product_draft_variants`. I tried to change it to `[product: [variants: :images]]` and it returns all `product_draft` with images through `product` and `variants` so I thought that joining these in one will return both. but it doesn't. It just returns all `product_draft` with images  through `product_draft_variants`

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I would try `[product_draft_variants: [:images], product: { variants: [:images] }]` (note the nested hash).

Answer (score 1):

You have to differentiate `images` in your `where` clauses.
There are two ways how to do it.

1. Use related models to build the query. Something like this.

```
ProductDraft.includes(param_includes)
            .where.not(product_draft_variants: {images: {id: nil}})
            .where(product: { variants: {images: {kind: ['', nil]}}})
```

2. Use pure sql in where

```
ProductDraft.includes(param_includes)
            .where('product_draft_variants.images.id IS NOT NULL')
            .where('products.images.variants.kind = '' OR products.images.variants.kind IS NULL')
```

Queries would be a bit different depending on your data structure. I don't know what image must have `id` or `kind`.